# Using CRUD with Ext JS 4 dynamic form

Tags: wcf, forms, extjs, crud, ashx

I'd like to build a simple form that I can use to create a record (C=Create), read the record data from a database (R=Read), update the record from a database (U=Update) and delete the record from a database (D=Delete).  I don't want to use PHP as in the Ext JS examples.  I'd prefer to use WCF or an HTTP Handler (*.ashx file) in ASP.NET.  Can someone help me with the code for this?  I don't need details on the database access.  I'm just struggling with getting the client code aspect, and what parameters and return types I should use on the server code methods.

**I'd like to mimic this architecture but use the Ext JS client code:**
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/283976/CRUD-Create-Read-Update-Delete

**And if you choose WCF, I'm using REST, not SOAP:**
http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=728

*I ordered the Ext JS 4 Cookbook for Web Applications on Amazon.com, but it's been on back order for 2 months now.*

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <title>...</title>

    <!-- ExtJS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../resources/css/ext-all.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../ext-all.js"></script>

    <!-- Shared -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../shared/example.css" />

    <!-- GC -->


    <!-- Example -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dynamic.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>CRUD example with Ext JS 4 dynamic form</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
Ext.require([
//'Ext.form.*',
//'Ext.layout.container.Column',
//'Ext.tab.Panel'
    '*'
]);

Ext.onReady(function () {
    Ext.QuickTips.init();

    var bd = Ext.getBody();

    /*
    * ================  Simple form  =======================
    */
    bd.createChild({ tag: 'h2', html: 'Form 1 - Very Simple' });

    var required = '<span style="color:red;font-weight:bold" data-qtip="Required">*</span>';

    var simple = Ext.widget({
        xtype: 'form',
        layout: 'form',
        collapsible: true,
        id: 'simpleForm',
        url: 'save-form.php',
        frame: true,
        title: 'Simple Form',
        bodyPadding: '5 5 0',
        width: 350,
        fieldDefaults: {
            msgTarget: 'side',
            labelWidth: 75
        },
        defaultType: 'textfield',
        items: [{
            fieldLabel: 'First Name',
            afterLabelTextTpl: required,
            name: 'first',
            allowBlank: false
        }, {
            fieldLabel: 'Last Name',
            afterLabelTextTpl: required,
            name: 'last'
        }, {
            fieldLabel: 'Company',
            name: 'company'
        }, {
            fieldLabel: 'Email',
            afterLabelTextTpl: required,
            name: 'email',
            vtype: 'email'
        }, {
            fieldLabel: 'DOB',
            name: 'dob',
            xtype: 'datefield'
        }, {
            fieldLabel: 'Age',
            name: 'age',
            xtype: 'numberfield',
            minValue: 0,
            maxValue: 100
        }, {
            xtype: 'timefield',
            fieldLabel: 'Time',
            name: 'time',
            minValue: '8:00am',
            maxValue: '6:00pm'
        }],

        buttons: [{
            text: 'Save'
        }, {
            text: 'Cancel'
        }]
    });

    simple.render(document.body);

});
```

[image]

Comment: http://peterkellner.net/2012/04/20/details-on-the-extjs-application-to-build-simple-crud-operation-using-models-and-stores/

Comment: This is ASP.NET MVC, not ASP.NET.  Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with MVC.  :-\

Comment: This seems to be the best example out there, that walks you from start to finish on an MVC application.  It recommends you follow the MVC guide (tutorial) that Sencha provides, which doesn't actually do any writing--it just emulates the writing.  The CouchDB non-relational de-normalized JSON document database structure is pretty interesting.  http://averydc.com/ee/index.php/blog/couchdb_extjs4_a_winning_combination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is kind of very vague and this is probably the main reason you're not getting any answers. I just launched rather big web application after 6mo development cycle with ExtJs  as a front end, entity framework and SQL Server as a back end.

There is really not so much difference from the ExtJs perspective comparing to say working with PHP - of course there are some quirks here and there, but after you configure WCF to provide you JSON data - there are very similar.

You can start by specifying different URLs in your proxy class (because WCF will handle UCD portion of CRUD in one SubmitChanges handler:

```
read: 'GetData',
update: 'SubmitChanges',
create: 'SubmitChanges',
destroy: 'SubmitChanges'
```

I'd be happy to help if you have any specific questions.

Comment: can you place this code into the code I already have, and update your answer?

Comment: I ended up using asmx, so I'll mark this as correct for now unless someone posts an answer with more detail.  Long term, I'd like to switch to WCF though.